# Ошибка при подключении базы данных Firebase Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

Столкнулся с проблемой что при попытке подключить бд. При добавлении зависимостей в pubspec.yaml и нажатии на Pub get крутится бесконечная загрузка и в консоли выводится ошибка

"Because todo depends on cloud_firestroe any which doesn't exist (could not find package cloud_firestroe at https://pub.dartlang.org ), version solving failed."

А при запуске приложения выводится

"pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 27 in 64 seconds...Because todo depends on cloud_firestroe any which doesn't exist (could not find package cloud_firestroe at https://pub.dartlang.org ), version solving failed."

Не могу разобраться в чем проблема. Кто то может сталкивался с подобным? Все делал по инструкции. Я только начинаю изучать fluuter и может допустил где-то ошибку.

Comment: У вас похоже что-то с доступом на https://pub.dev/ или https://pub.dartlang.org. Попробуйте включить vpn и сделать pub get

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `flutter packages get` попробуйте ввести `pub get packages`